# free jira cloud test management add on

Tags: jira, jira-plugin

I was looking around for some time, but couldn' t find a free add-on to manage test cases, test plans et scenarios ect.

Do you know any who is free that can be installed on a Jira cloud solution ? or should i create my own custom Jira project for it, if there is no free one

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try the TestFLO app - it's available for both Server and Cloud instances of Jira. Not fully free, but at least you've got a free trial :) You can find it on Atlassian Marketplace, just like any app for Jira.